# How does the Signal Protocol, used by WhatsApp, work?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, whatsapp

I want to understand the process of the Signal Protocol. I have google it, but I am unable to find any good article or tutorial.

I want to understand the basic definition and functionality of the Signal Protocol, and it would be great if any diagram describing the process is available.

Comment: I'd like to hear more about this too but it would get better attention on here if you demonstrated what you do know and put forth your own understanding of how it works so that people on here can correct you and / or add to your understanding.  For example, the Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(software)) has diagrams and basic definition and functionality.  Read that and expand your question.

Comment: You may want to listen / read the transcript of the Security Now podcast, episode 555 - "WhatsApp". Transcript https://www.grc.com/sn/sn-555.htm Audio: http://media.GRC.com/sn/SN-555.mp3

It's about WhatsApp, but very much goes into detail of the underlying protocol, which is Signal. The topic starts about half way in.

Answer (score 17):

Take a look at this [technical white paper](https://www.whatsapp.com/security/WhatsApp-Security-Whitepaper.pdf) from WhatsApp, they recently moved to the Signal Protocol for e2e encryption.

### Public Key Types

- `Identity Key Pair` – A long-term Curve25519 key pair,
  generated at install time.
- `Signed Pre Key` – A medium-term Curve25519 key pair,
  generated at install time, signed by the Identity Key, and rotated
  on a periodic timed basis.
- `One-Time Pre Keys` – A queue of Curve25519 key pairs for one
  time use, generated at install time, and replenished as needed.
  Session Key Types
- `Root Key` – A 32-byte value that is used to create Chain Keys.
- `Chain Key` – A 32-byte value that is used to create Message
  Keys.
- `Message Key` – An 80-byte value that is used to encrypt message
  contents. 32 bytes are used for an AES-256 key, 32 bytes for a
  HMAC-SHA256 key, and 16 bytes for an IV.

### To establish a session:

1. The initiating client (“initiator”) requests the public `Identity Key`,
   public `Signed Pre Key`, and a single public `One-Time Pre Key`
   for the recipient.
2. The server returns the requested public key values. A `One-Time
   Pre Key` is only used once, so it is removed from server storage
   after being requested. If the recipient’s latest batch of `One-Time
   Pre Keys` has been consumed and the recipient has not replenished
   them, no `One-Time Pre Key` will be returned.
3. The initiator saves the recipient’s `Identity Key` as `Irecipient`, the
   `Signed Pre Key` as `Srecipient`, and the `One-Time Pre Key` as
   `Orecipient`.
4. The initiator generates an ephemeral Curve25519 key pair, `Einitiator`.
5. The initiator loads its own `Identity Key` as `Iinitiator`.
6. The initiator calculates a master secret as `master_secret =
   ECDH(Iinitiator, Srecipient) || ECDH(Einitiator, Irecipient) ||
   ECDH(Einitiator, Srecipient) || ECDH(Einitiator, Orecipient)`.
   If there is no `One Time Pre Key`, the final ECDH is omitted.
7. The initiator uses HKDF to create a `Root Key` and `Chain Keys`
   from the `master_secret`.

### Receiving Session Setup

After building a long-running encryption session, the initiator can immediately
start sending messages to the recipient, even if the recipient is offline.
Until the recipient responds, the initiator includes the information (in the
header of all messages sent) that the recipient requires to build a corresponding
session. This includes the initiator’s `Einitiator` and `Iinitiator`.

When the recipient receives a message that includes session setup
information:

1. The recipient calculates the corresponding `master_secret` using
   its own private keys and the public keys advertised in the header of
   the incoming message.
2. The recipient deletes the `One-Time Pre Key` used by the initiator.
3. The initiator uses HKDF to derive a corresponding `Root Key` and
   `Chain Keys` from the `master_secret`.

Comment: In the whitepaper, it is stated that `message_key = HMAC-SHA256(chain_key, 0x01)` and also it is stated that `message_key` is 80 bytes. How is that possible? `HMAC-SHA256` has output size of 32 bytes.

Comment: @Ramazan Great question. The other resources I've looked at don't describe the `message_key` in that way. I wonder if that section of the whitepaper is broken.
https://github.com/trevp/double_ratchet/wiki
https://whispersystems.org/blog/advanced-ratcheting/

Comment: Hi, is there a short explanation of why the protocol has to use so many keys ? I thought one long-lived identity key and one one-time key generated for each message would suffice to provide authentication and forward secrecy.

Comment: What do you mean with 'rotated on a periodic timed basis'?

Comment: @Richard This text is directly from the PDF document. I assume it means that a maximum lifetime is used for this key and is rotated when that lifetime expires.

Comment: @Ramazan This might no longer be relevant to you, but I found some signal doc that explains how to go from 32-byte HMAC output to the 80-byte value used by whatsapp using HKDF. See the recommendations for ENCRYPT here: https://signal.org/docs/specifications/doubleratchet/#recommended-cryptographic-algorithms

Comment: @joshperry thank you for the great explanation. One doubt I had: Why can't someone snoop in on the keys server is sending to the initiator and use that because everything there seems public. Pardon my lack of understanding but does the math magic lie in use of private keys on recipient side to be able to decrypt the message. And if it requires private key of recipient then how does conversation go forward, how can initiator read recipient's subsequent reply?